# How Can I add Fields in wp-option table?

Tags: plugin-development, options

I want to activate my plugin and I want to create fields in "wp_option" table. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to create a field, [`add_option()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_option) will do just fine, but I would strongly recommend using [`update_option()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option) instead, as it tends to be the better choice for most applications.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the Codex entry for Plugin Development - specifically the [WordPress Options Mechanism](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin#WordPress_Options_Mechanism) section. See also: [Creating Options Pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages), and especially [Settings API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API).